# Gulp: lossy recompression of images when some are broken

Tags: imagemagick, gulp, gulp-imagemin

I have a set of ~18,000 jpg files that I need to optimize/recompress.

I tried almost every gulp image optimization plugin out there, and every plugin at some point gives an error with no suggestion on what file is the reason for it.
Here's what `gulp-image-resize` ends with:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Error: Command failed: gm identify: No decode delegate for this image format (/var/folders/ns/85cnwvcx5ysb7jzr8hh_k4r80000gn/T/gmROZu8m).
gm identify: Request did not return an image.

    at finish (/Users/mvasin/Sites/process images/node_modules/gulp-gm/index.js:40:21)
    at gm. (/Users/mvasin/Sites/process images/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:485:30)
    at emitMany (events.js:108:13)
    at gm.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at gm. (/Users/mvasin/Sites/process images/node_modules/gm/lib/getters.js:70:16)
    at cb (/Users/mvasin/Sites/process images/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:318:16)
    at ChildProcess.proc.on.onExit (/Users/mvasin/Sites/process images/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:293:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
```

Here's `gulp-gm`'s blue screen:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Stream yields empty buffer
    at Socket. (/Users/mvasin/Sites/process images/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:57:17)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:893:12)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:17)
a228:process images mvasin$ gulp GraphicsMagick
```

`gulp-responsive`:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format
    at Error (native)
```

`gulp-sharp-resize`:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format
    at Error (native)
```

Beautiful! I'll sort through all of my 18,000 images and hopefully will figure out the one with 'unsupported image format'. Stick around, I'll be right back. 

Now comes `imagemin-jpeg-recompress`:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Unsupported color conversion request

    at ChildProcess. (/Users/mvasin/Sites/process images/node_modules/imagemin-jpeg-recompress/index.js:101:11)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:817:16)
    at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

You got the idea...

`gulp-imagemin` stops on error as well.

I tried to resort to desktop mac app ImageOptim (it has 'lossy' deep down in the settings), but on really huge image sets it silently stops processing sometime in the middle because of internal error.

And I'd like to preserve gulp workflow anyway.

Comment: Are you in an environment where you could run straightforward shell commands in a terminal against your images? If so, ImageMagick has a tool called `identify` that can check an image's integrity. You could combine that with `GNU Parallel` to get some seriously fast checking done... try making a copy of a few hundred and running this `parallel identify ::: *.jpg`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Mark! How to check images recursively? It's across inner directories, and `parallel identify ::: *.jpg` gives "identify: unable to open image `**/*.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701" error.

Comment: Try something like `find topDirectory -name \*.jpg | parallel identify {}`

Comment: It gives a very verbose output, but I occasionally found a way: I run it with `> test.txt` in the end. It prints files info to `test.txt` and outputs error files directly to console. Now I'll try to delete those manually and see if it helps to gulp plugins.

Comment: No, it didn't help. I checked twice, running command above to make sure there are no error images, and still get  `events.js:141 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`. That's a weird thing! Such a buzz about gulpifing images, while it's not really useful for real projects at the moment if sorce image files are not sterile.

Comment: Mark, GNU Parallel and ImageMagick's CLI is overwhelming, can you please suggest a command to recompress all `jpg` with quality 70% and minify `png` and `gif` within `somedir`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) to prevent stoping gulp task on incorrect images.

It can also show which image causes an error.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.jpg')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.responsive({
      ...
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU Parallel` and `ImageMagick`, you could recompress all JPEG images and strip EXIF data like this:

```
parallel convert {} -quality 70% -strip {} ::: *.jpg
```

The two `{}` represent the input filename and the output filename. Please try this on a COPY of your files and check whether you are happy with the results and with the copyright and EXIF data being stripped BEFORE you do it on your real data.

If you have too many files for the shell to expand, you can pump the filenames in via `stdin` like this:

```
find TOPDIR -iname *.jpg | parallel convert {} -quality 70% -strip {}
```

I don't use `pngcrush` myself, but assume you could do:

```
parallel pngcrush {} {} ::: *.png
```

Add `--eta` after the word `parallel` if you like watching progress meters and want the Estimated Time of Arrival.

```
parallel --eta pngcrush {} {} ::: *.png
```

Comment: It worked! Together with `gulp-shell` it can probably make it's way to gulp.

Comment: Why not to use ImageMagick for png as well?

Comment: `:::` is GNU Parallel syntax to indicate the end of command and the start of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Mh, maybe this helps someone: 
Also spend some hours spiking around these strange imagemagick error messages.
In my case a simple correction on the source image path solved it:

`gulp.src('path/to/imagesrc/*')`
vs. 
`gulp.src('path/to/imagesrc/*.jpg')`

my gulp task around it creates an thumbnail folder in the imagesrc folder right away. an this was the problem. the * selector included this thumbnail folder and piped it to imagemagick functions, which certainly cannot handle it.